# importing native iOS framework to nativescript plugin

Tags: ios, plugins, nativescript

I'm trying to access an iOS framework class from my NativeScript plugin.

Right now, this plugin only has a `SampleClass` with a `test` method that returns a number, but it will change soon. For now, what I'm trying to do is to call the class method from that native framework.

I have seen some examples where the plugin seed extends an iOS base class and creates everything there, but in this case, I want to use a `.framework` file.

I'm assuming this would be equivalent to use some `.aar` Android file. In that case, I've seen the call would be made with something like this

```
var c = java.lang.Class.forName("org.test.plugin.name.MyActivity");
```

So, I have copied the `.framework` file to `platforms/ios`, my question is  about how to get this `SampleClass` method.

Also, I've seen some documentation that recommends the use of CocoaPods. I'm new to iOS development and still don't get this at all, but if my application won't use any native dependency, would this be necessary? Should I need another files? (got a default `Info.plist` and `build.xcconfig`)

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I think if you just want to access classes from framework, then you don't need any extra steps. Once the framework file is copied to platforms/ios, it should be accessible in the plugin.

Comment: @Manoj what I've got is "Cannot find name 'SampleClass'."

Comment: If you using TypeScript, then you should declare it. Like `declare var SampleClass` so the compiler will ignore that. If you are interested in getting all classes and methods listed, then you should generate declaration files for the library with the steps [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/Use-Native-iOS-Libraries#troubleshooting).

Comment: @Manoj that did the trick (I don't know what part of the documentation says that, but I'm glad it worked) Thank you. Now I'm facing a lipo error, but that would be another question...

Comment: Glad that worked, so now I understood exactly what you were looking for hence added a detail answer which might help others to find it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using TypeScript, you have to either declare the classes like,

```
// iOS
declare var SampleClass;

// Android
declare var org;
```

then you may access all available packages / classes / methods directly.

```
// Android
const MyActivity = org.test.plugin.name.MyActivity; 

// iOS
SampleClass.new()
```

If you like intellisense support for these libraries, then you may even generate declaration files for both [iOS](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/Use-Native-iOS-Libraries#troubleshooting) & [Android](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/metadata/generating-typescript-declarations) libraries with the given steps in the docs.